# How to query an unknown number tax_query

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am doing a taxonomy search, but don´t know how many tax_queries will be needed. Seems like I could do an unlimited `$tq_args[0]`, `$tq_args[1]`, etc. to be safe. But that seems stupid. What is the proper PHP/Wordpress-way of doing this?

```
foreach ($_GET[filter] AS $key => $value) {

        foreach ($value AS $key2 => $value2) {
            $terms[] = $value2;
        }

        $tq_args[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => $key,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $terms
        );
}


    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'it_produkt',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            $tq_args[0],
            $tq_args[1],
            $tq_args[2],
            $tq_args[3],
            $tq_args[4],
            $tq_args[5]
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to add all elements of array $tq_args into array $args['tax_query']

try this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'it_produkt',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND'
    )
);
$args['tax_query'] = array_merge($args['tax_query'], $tq_args);
```